# Issues trying to run electron based application?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am trying to create a simple Electron based application, based on the instructions at http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/ , which provide the code below. When I do trying running it with electron 1.4.4 and NodeJS 6.7.0 I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/proj/src/goelectron.js:29:4)
```

The code follows:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)

  // Open the DevTools.
  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

This suggests that 'app' is undefined, but I am not familiar with the notation the provides `const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')`, so I am unsure how to check what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is intended to be run with the 'electron' command, so since I did not install it globally (assuming I am in my project directory):

```
node_modules/.bin/electron ./src/goelectron.js
```

otherwise if I had, it would be:

```
electron ./src/goelectron.js
```

Comment: You shouldn't install `electron` globally, instead you should add an NPM script to your `package.json` that runs `electron src/goelectron.js`.

Comment: The suggestion of adding to the package.json is useful - thanks